# How to disable "always include" class in Composer autoload_static.php

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

Composer in autoload_static.php use class that I don't need them in every app request.

```
'd5fa61a7f6cbc1df09dd4df84549a2dc' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/rospdf/pdf-php/src/Cpdf.php',
'2d15964294879de66053d54f6bde65d7' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/rospdf/pdf-php/src/Cezpdf.php',
```

How to remove them from this autoload file? I can delete/comment them manually but every Composer update this file is re-generated.

I try to add in my main composer.json:
*"exclude-from-classmap": ["vendor/rospdf/pdf-php/src/"]*
& run *composer dump-autoload* bo those class are still in there.

Comment: Why would you need to do this? There's virtually no overhead here.

Comment: All classes from autoload_static.php (public static $files = array()) are included in every request to my app and take some script memory and execution time. Heavy Cpdf.php is used only in one place in code - very rarely.

Comment: Probably the best what you can get is to fork package and change autoloading settings. Or overwrite it using repository with `package` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trick the autoloader of composer and let him think those are already loaded:

```
<?php

// Setting global variable:
$GLOBALS["__composer_autoload_files"] = [
    "d5fa61a7f6cbc1df09dd4df84549a2dc" => true,
    "2d15964294879de66053d54f6bde65d7" => true,
];

require "vendor/autoload.php";
```

But this needs to happen **before** the `vendor/autoload.php` is included.